# Primeng: p-calendar partially hidden behind p-dialog

Tags: calendar, dialog, primeng

Working in Angular with primeng, the popup of the p-calendar component not showing in the expected way (clipping with other components), when placed inside a p-dialog.

For example: it is hidden behind other elements by default.

[Calendar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFkzX.png)

:)

Comment: If you're going to ask and answer your own questions, can you please write the questions in such a way that people might be able to search for them, and then find them. Calendar "not showing in the expected way" isn't clear at all and is unlikely to appear in any search. A clear question should explain the desired behaviour, the actual behaviour and a [mre] of the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: I know his question is not phrased ideally, but I did find the question as one of the first results on google for the issue and it provided the solution.

Comment: The question is useful and clear enough for people having the same problem, and the answers are useful. So why was it closed by someone whose profile suggests that he does not know much about the Angular technology?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try  next

```
<p-calendar appendTo="body"
```

Comment: Can't test it now, I don't have the enviroment setup, make me now if this solution works better and i change the post answer! thx

Comment: Tested it and worked like a charm. My case is a little different though since I am using AngularMaterial dialog and a p-calendar picker inside

Answer (score 0):

Just add this pice of code that make your date picker(the calendar component, not the input field) stay in front of other elements:

```
.ui-datepicker{
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 999;
}
```